How to put different splits into one filter without combining the data from the splits back together?
I'm a Tableau newbie. I have a list of companies with a combined list of majors. I divided my majors list into 10 different splits, how can I put all my splits into one filter without combining the data again?
I want to have a filter that contains all the majors from my splits so I can filter by each single major.
I tried to create a pivot table but some of the splits have blank cells, which doesn't allow me to create the pivot table.
I tried to use a calculated field but adding the splits puts the information back together into combined lists.

Show simplified sample data to get help

Pivot and then filter out nulls
